# save image in a folder using nodeJS and angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

save image in a folder using nodeJS and angularJS

Hi, i want save images in a folder, I have my backEnd in NodeJS and my frondEnd in AngularJS using ng-flow; my angular service code is the following

```
        addImages : function (file) {
            var uploadUrl = localPath + "addImages";
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file', file);
            return $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers:    {   'Content-Type': undefined,
                                'file-name' : undefined,
                                'file-location' : undefined,
                                'user-id' : undefined
                            }
            });
        }
```

and i have the following POST service in Node

```
router.post('/addImages', function (req, res) {
        console.log(req);
    var tempPath = req.files.file.path;
        console.log(tempPath);
    var targetPath = path.resolve('/../static/image/image.png');

        console.log(targetPath);
        console.log(req.files.file.name);
    if (path.extname(req.files.file.name).toLowerCase() === '.png') {
        fs.rename(tempPath, targetPath, function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Upload completed!");
        });
    } else {
        fs.unlink(tempPath, function () {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.error("Only .png files are allowed!");
        });
    }
    // ...
});
```

the error that i get is `POST /assetImage/addImages 500`

someone know a more easy form to get a image in angular and save in a folder using node?

**Edit**

when I print file using console.log i get o file object like `File { name: "howls-moving-castle-40994-1920x1200…", lastModified: 1431122408000, lastModifiedDate: Date 2015-05-08T22:00:08.000Z, size: 910465, type: "image/jpeg" }` but when print the fd get a empty object `FormData {  }` I intentend pass file whitout using `formData` but in node get a Empty object to

Comment: Try to select the first file from array, fd.append("file", files[0]). And check req in console log, as you already do. Is it as expected?

Comment: hi @fubbe thanks for your answer, I edit the question what the result, the fd object are empty and i cant pass the file directly

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Express.js, `body-parser` does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in the following modules:

busboy

multiparty

formidable

multer

See the [suggested modules here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#readme) for parsing multipart bodies.